# Long process method with LINQ Query should be in Queue

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a method which reduces `availQty` by 10 on current qty after a long process.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<string> DecreaseInvByTen()
        {
            using (var tran = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {
                    var invReduce = _context.Inventorys.Where(w=>w.id == 1).FirstOrDefault(); // availQty is 100.

                    Thread.Sleep(60000); // Goes some long process.
                    invReduce.availQty -= 10;
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    tran.Commit();
                    return invReduce.availQty.ToString();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tran.Rollback();
                    return ex.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

When three users access this method at a time, expected availQty should be 70 after 3 executions whereas this method returns 90, even after 3 executions, as it is long process every user gets `availQty` 100 at the line `var invReduce...`

How do I solve this problem?

I am using `Asp.Net Core 2.2` with `Code-First`, `Postgresql`. I do not want to inform user about current `availQty`, simply reduce by 10 after previous request completes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ConcurrencyCheckAttribute`:

```
public class Inventory
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int availQty {get;set;}
}

try
{
    //your code...
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    //so, instead of:
    //update Inventorys
    //set availQty = 90 where id = 1
    //will be:
    //update Inventorys
    //set availQty = 90 where id = 1 and availQty = 100
    //i.e, if availQty has been already decrement, no rows will be affected 
    //and exception below will be thrown.
}
catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
{
    //TODO: reread value from database, updated by another request, and decrement it again
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of lock here

```
   private readonly object locker = new object();

   public async Task<string> DecreaseInvByTen()
    {
        using (var tran = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
               lock(locker) {
                var invReduce = _context.Inventorys.Where(w=>w.id == 1).FirstOrDefault(); // availQty is 100.

                Thread.Sleep(60000); // Goes some long process.
                invReduce.availQty -= 10;
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                tran.Commit();
              }
                return invReduce.availQty.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tran.Rollback();
                return ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: static instead of readonly is working in my case but I have 3 methods, 1st for decrease qty by 10, 2nd for increase qty by 10, 3rd one for increase qty by parameter val. In such case, I may need to lock with same object in 3 methods which seems to be not correct. Is there row lock kind operation to do so?